# Is it possible to choose which objects get synchronized in AWS Managed AD?

Tags: active-directory, amazon-web-services, aws-directory-service

In Azure AD Connect Sync, [it is possible to configure filtering](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-configure-filtering). This is described as:

> By using filtering, you can control which objects appear in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) from your on-premises directory. The default configuration takes all objects in all domains in the configured forests.

I need this similar functionality in AWS Managed AD synchronized to an on-premises directory. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that AWS managed AD does any sync at all to your on-prem AD.  It uses AD trusts to make your On-Prem credentials "available" in AWS.
See this [use case](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/usecase5.html) in the docs for more